# Which is the fastest method to copy a oracle table with 110 million data?

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 12.1 version . 
My task is to copy a table a into another table a_copy in the same schema .
Table a has 110 million rows and table is of 15Gigs size. 
Database is a heavy load database and i want to know which is the best and safe method to copy data.

Methods which i am aware of :

1. Create table a_copy as select * from a;
2. create a table a_copy, then insert from a in batches.

Problems, that can occur. Undo space issues/rollback issues.
We should also avoid high number of commits. 
I am not sure if 
SET ARRAYSIZE ( that helps to specify number of rows in a batch ) and SET COPYCOMMIT (allowing a commit for a certain number of batch) options of sqlplus works with INSERT. These options work with COPY command of sqlplus.

3. Datapump backup the table and restore.

Can anyone suggest which is the best and safest as per your experiences ? I take this as a concern , since my database load is high.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious: Why do you want to do that? Why don't you just query the original table?

Comment: 1. would be best way to go. If possible to parallelize SELECT even better. Do not forget to create indexes, constraints (primary key, unique constraints, foreign keys), triggers and default values, as these, if used, will not be created on new table. Also, needed to find logic for index names on second table (as index names can not be the same)

Comment: @Robert . My team would like to test some kind of data devaluation on the production data. So they dont want to do first in the original table. In test environment, we dont have the similar data to test.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.